# how to install web application from a .msi file , created using wix?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, wix, msdn

I created a small web application in c# and wanted to create a installer for the web app and started so, using wix and i come up with the .msi file(installer) with a .wixpdb file.
Now, when i click on the .msi setup file ,installation is getting started and ending up with noting.

steps i followed is,

1. create web application.
2. build and publish.
3. harvest the publish folder and thats creates me a .wxs file.
4. create a setup project in the same solution of my web app.
5. add .wxs from step3 to the setup project.
6. build the setup project it create a .msi(installer) and .wixpdb file.

My Doubt here is that, how can i run the installer that will create a service/web application and installed locally.

Comment: 1. Explain "ending up with nothing"?
2. Explain the debugging steps that you did till now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is quite simple, of course we just need to double click the installer, but before that we need to add 
    `<UIRef Id="MyWebUI" />` in FileName.wxs file  and define some UI dialogs in the .wxs file, that is more cleary explained here
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115036/Creating-WIX-Installer-for-ASP-NET-Web-Application.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately WIX harvesting will not create a web application/web site for you automagically, when you harvest a "published" application. It will just produce the code to copy files. In WIX, you have to add this functionality yourself. In comparison with VS installer for example, you've got much more to do, and the rabbit's hole appears to be much deeper.. Take a look here for example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115036/Creating-WIX-Installer-for-ASP-NET-Web-Application

http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/10/create-an-installer-for-website-with-wix-part-1/